# Proving Dedekind finite implies finite assuming countable choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'd like to show that if a set $X$ is Dedekind finite then is is finite if we assume $(AC)_{\aleph_0}$. As set $X$ is called Dedekind finite if the following equivalent conditions are satisfied: (a) there is no injection $\omega \hookrightarrow X$ (b) every injection $X \to X$ is also a surjection.

Countable choice $(AC)_{\aleph_0}$ says that every contable family of non-empty, pairwise disjoint sets has a choice function.

There is the following theorem:

[image]

from which I can prove what I want as follows: Pick an $x_0 \in X$. Define $G(F(0), \dots, F(n-1)) = \{x_0\}$ if $x_0 \notin \bigcup F(k)$ and $G(F(0), \dots , F(n-1)) = X \setminus \bigcup F(k)$ otherwise. Also, $G(\varnothing) = \{x_0\}$. Let $F: \omega \to X$ be as in the theorem. Then $F$ is injective by construction.

The problem with that is that I suspect that the proof of theorem 24 needs countable choice. So what I am after is the following: consider the generalisation of theorem 24:

[image]

(note the typo in $(R^\ast)$, it should be $F(z) \in G^\ast (F \mid I(z), z)$), and its proof (assuming AC):

[image]

I want to modify this proof to prove the countable version of the theorem. But I can't seem to manage. I need a countable set $\{G^\ast \mid \{\langle f,z \rangle \} : \langle f,z \rangle \in dom(G^\ast) \}$. Ideas I had were along the lines of picking $f_0(x) = x_0$ the constant function and then to consider $\{G^\ast \mid \{\langle f_0,n \rangle \} : \langle f_0,n \rangle \in dom(G^\ast) \}$ but what then?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the statement “Dedekind finite implies finite”, what definition of “finite” are you using?  “$X$ is finite if for some $n$, $X$ has a bijection with $\{1 \ldots n\}$”?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be an infinite set. For $n\in\omega$ let $$A_n=\{\langle a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}\rangle\mid\forall i: a_i\in X\land\forall i,j: i\neq j\implies a_i\neq a_j\}$$
Because $X$ is infinite every $A_n$ is non-empty.

Use countable choice to choose $f_n\in A_n$. Now show that the union of the ranges of the $f_n$ is **an enumerated union** which is therefore well-ordered. This union cannot be finite, otherwise there would be some $f_k$ in which appears an element not in the union. Therefore it is countably infinite, as wanted.

---

Note that generally the principle of recursive construction is in fact *stronger* than countable choice and it is equivalent to the principle of Dependent Choice. (In fact this appears in the paragraph after the exercise you are trying to solve.)

Comment: What is an enumerated union and why is it in bold face? And how do you finish the proof?

Comment: What do you map $n$ to?

Comment: Enumerated union is the union of sets where their enumeration is also given to you. It is in bold so you can't miss it. *You* should finish the proof by showing this is a countably infinite subset of $X$.

Comment: Ok, let's try this: $f: \omega \to \{f_n\}_{n \in \omega}, n \mapsto f_n$ and $f_n : A_n \to X$ ($f_n \in A_n$). Then take $g: \omega \to \omega \times \omega$ be a bijection and define $F: \omega \to X, n \mapsto f(g(n)_0)(g(n)_1)$. Then $F$ is an injection from $\omega \to X$.

Comment: No, $f_n\in A_n$, and $f_n\colon n\to X$. But aside for that point, almost. Note that each $f_n$ only counts a finite number of elements, and the same elements may appear more than once. However you can show that $F(n)=f_{g(n)_0}(g(n)_1)$ (whenever defined, and some fixed value otherwise) is a surjection from $\omega$ onto an infinite subset of $X$. Surjections from well-ordered domains can be reversed and therefore there $X$ has a countably infinite subset.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: No, actually. If you read my question you will notice that I want to prove _countable_ recursive construction. And I'm sure that's possible using countable choice.

Comment: What is the **countable** recursive construction? And why do you think you can prove it using countable choice?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question (Dedekind finite implies finite), not your second (principle of generalised recursive constructions): we prove the contrapositive, showing that infinite implies Dedekind-infinite.

Suppose $X$ is infinite, i.e. has no bijection with $\{1 \ldots n \}$, for any $n \in \omega$.  Then by induction on $n$, there exists for each $n \in \omega$ some injection $f : \{1 \ldots n\} \to X$.

By countable choice, choose for each $n$ some such injection $f_n$.  Now define an injection $f_\omega : \omega \to X$ by taking $f_\omega(n)$ to be $f_n(i)$, for the least $i$ such that $f_n(i)$ has not perviously appeared as a value of $f_\omega(n)$.

This gives an injection $\omega \to X$, showing that $X$ is Dedekind-infinite, as desired.

Comment: Where does the contradiction comes in? Did you mean contrapositive? This is not contrapositive either. This is a direct proof...

Comment: You’re right, I should have said contrapositive (I’ve been working in constructive maths too long; classical proofs no longer feel like a native language to me).  But this is surely the contrapositive of the statement OP originally asked for, isn’t it?

Comment: You constructivists and your crazy avoidance from negations. :-)

Comment: (As a logical note, though: in general, the principle “any implication is equivalent to its contrapositive” is equivalent to the principle of proof by contradiction, even over a very minimal logical background; hence why I tend to forget to distinguish between them.)

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong. 1. Your injection $f_\omega : \omega \to X$ is constructed on the basis of Principle of Generalized Recursive Construction (**Theorem 5** in the picture in the OP's post) in the sense that $f_\omega(n)$ depends on $f_\omega(1),f_\omega(2),\cdots,f_\omega(n-1)$? 2. Principle of Generalized Recursive Construction (**Theorem 5** in the picture in the OP's post) is in fact equivalent to Axiom of Dependent Choice.

Comment: @LeAnhDung: No, my argument doesn’t require Dependent Choice/PGRC.  DC/PGRC is required for defining a function recursively if, at the successor stage, all you know in advance is that there exists *some* possible “next value” satisfying the desired property (i.e. lying in the function $G^*$, in the statement from the OP).  Recursively defining a function on $\omega$ whose value is *uniquely* specified at each stage (as in my construction of $f_\omega$ from the sequence of injections $f_n$) does not require DC/PGRC.  The only place my answer uses any choice is in picking the sequence $f_n$.

Comment: There are various versions of Recursion Theorem. Could you please mention explicitly which version you are using to construct  $f_\omega : \omega \to X$? From your above explanation, I understood that your construction does not appeal to any form of Axiom of Choice, but I found hard to find your versions of Recursion Theorem.

Comment: I didn’t have any particular from in mind — there are lots that suffice. E.g. “Suppose you have a set $P$, some $p_0 \in P$, and a function $h : \mathbb{N} \times P \to P$. Then there’s a unique function $g : \mathbb{N} \to P$ such that $g(0)=p_0$ and for each $n$, $g(n+1)=h(n,g(n))$.” The proof of this is a direct induction, needing no choice. Then my answer applies it with $P$ being the set of all injections from any initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$, $p_0$ the empty function, and $h(n,k)$ as the extension of $k$ using $f_n$, if possible, or otherwise $k$.