# How do i prove that "an infinite set contains a countable subset" using AC$_\omega$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The proof for this using Dependent choice, is easy. I forgot how to prove this with only AC$_\omega$. Could someone help?

I feel really sorry that i keep asking these basic questions.. This would be my last one. Thank you in advance

Comment: Quite often basic questions are exactly the questions that should be asked. If that is the case here then there is no reason to feel sorry.

Comment: I think I posted an answer for this at least twice on the site. I have the feeling that one of the times wasn't that long ago, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving Dedekind finite implies finite assuming countable choice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250119/proving-dedekind-finite-implies-finite-assuming-countable-choice)

Comment: I found one, there as definitely others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a infinite set, define
$$
A_n =\{C\subset X : |C|=n\}.
$$
If $n\ge 1$ then $A_n$ is nonempty. So we can choose $S_n\in A_n$ for each $n\ge 1$. You can prove $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} A_n$ is countable subset of $X$ using the countable axiom of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be an infinite set.

All that is required is define an injective sequence $a: \mathbb N \to X$.

Proposition 1: Suppose we have an injection $\rho : \{0,1,\dots,n\} \to X$. Select any element $\hat x$ not in the image of $\rho$. Then $\rho$ can be extended to a new injective funtion by mapping

$\qquad {n+1} \to \hat x$.

Select any element $a_0 \in X$ and set $a(0) = a_0$. Using proposition 1 and recursion, we can create an injective sequence into $X$.

Of course we are using $AC_ω$ here.